# Dynamic variables based on condition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make the property value of an object to be dynamic based on a given condition.

For example, the property value would become `Red` if the viewport width is `<= 1280` , else it would be `Yellow` .

I'm trying to use the `if...else` statement but it shows an error: `SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters`.

```js
const firstData = {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280) {
    apple: 'Red'
  } else {
    apple: 'Yellow'
  }
};

// Or

const secondData = {
  apple: if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280) {
    return "Red"
  } else {
    return "Yellow"
  }
};

console.log(firstData, secondData);
```

Comment: What is the error message? Welcome to SO. Please be more specific. Hint: You cannot use this kind of code in an object declaration. Instead use the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72965093/1705829).

Comment: @Timo Thanks, I've updated the question to show what is the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ternary operator to do it cleaner.

```js
const data = {
  apple: document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280 ? "Red" : "Yellow",
};

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

If You want one line condition then above answer is best but with more conditions you can do something or define the function else where then run it

```js
const obj = {
    apple: (() => {
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280) {
            return 'Red';
        } else {
            return 'Yellow';
        }
    })(),
};
```

or you can even define dynamic properties

```
const obj = {
    ...(() => {
        if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280) {
            return { color: 'Red' };
        } else {
            return { color1: 'Yellow' };
        }
    })(),
    color3: 'red',
};
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use statement as object value. Instead of this you can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
const object = {
    apple: document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1280 ? 'Red' : 'Yellow', 
}
```